# Создание svg картинки с анимацией

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть 2 картинки. Как из них сделать один svg файл с анимацией при наведении (фаербол летит от рук в сторону). Буду очень благодарен!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, наверное:

```css
image#man + image {
  opacity: 0;
}

image#man:hover + image {
  transform: translate(600px,0);
  animation: fireball 1s;
}

@keyframes fireball{
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:translate(0,0);
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(600px,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 550 150">
  <image id="man" height="150" width="150" 
    xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDV5v.png"></image> 
  <image id="fireball" x="80" y="28" height="50" width="50" 
    xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eRcr.png"></image>
</svg>
```